# Javascript : Event Listener not working

Tags: javascript

I am a javascript beginner and trying to make a simple list to which a user can add or remove items. Adding items to the list works but the event listeners won't work on removing an item.

```js
txt = document.getElementById('txt_input');
submit = document.getElementById('txt_submit');
removeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
window.onload = txt.focus();
submit.onclick = addToList;

for (var i = 0; i < removeBtn.length; i++) {
  if (document.querySelector("li") !== null) {
   removeBtn[i].onclick = removeFromList;
  }     
}

function removeFromList(e) {
  event.target.parentNode.outerHTML = "";
}

function createRemoveButton(parent) {
  var listBtn = document.createElement('input');
  listBtn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
  listBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Remove');
  listBtn.setAttribute('class', 'remove');
  listBtn.style.marginLeft = '20px';
  parent.appendChild(listBtn);
}
var list;

function addToList() {
  if (document.querySelector("ul") === null) {
    list = document.createElement('ul');
  }
  var listItem = document.createElement('li');
  var txtNode = document.createTextNode(txt.value);
  listItem.appendChild(txtNode);
  createRemoveButton(listItem);
  list.appendChild(listItem);
  document.body.appendChild(list);
  txt.value = '';
  txt.focus();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt_input">
<input type="submit" value="Add" id="txt_submit">
```

Comment: The issue is that you are trying to bind event handlers on elements that don't exist yet. You need to look into [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)

Comment: The other thing you can do is say `listBtn.onclick = removeFromList` after you create the remove button in your `createRemoveButton` function before adding it to the DOM.

Comment: Yes, mhodges is correct. Your loop at the top doesn't find any elements to bind events to. You need to add the event listener as in the function that creates the button. You have the variable: listBtn, so assign the listener to it.

Comment: that could simply be solved by adding an if condition in the for loop which checks for the element before binding an event to that element... which i just did by editing the code but it still doesn't works...

Comment: `window.onload = txt.focus();` is also wrong

Comment: @epascarello How so ?

Comment: because the code is basically `txt.focus(); window.onload = undefined` It is calling focus and assigning what it returns to the event listener, it is not calling focus onload.

Comment: @epascarello thanx for the correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You have two main problems

You're using an undeclared variable `event`

```
function removeFromList(e) {
  event.target.parentNode.outerHTML = "";
  ^
```

You need to bind the `click` event to your new element.

## Look at this code snippet with those fixes.

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="txt_input">
  <input type="submit" value="Add" id="txt_submit">

  <script>
    txt = document.getElementById('txt_input');
    submit = document.getElementById('txt_submit');
    removeBtn = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');

    window.onload = txt.focus();
    submit.onclick = addToList;

    for (var i = 0; i < removeBtn.length; i++) {
      removeBtn[i].onclick = removeFromList;
    }


    function removeFromList(e) {
      e.target.parentNode.outerHTML = "";
    }


    function createRemoveButton(parent) {
      var listBtn = document.createElement('input');
      listBtn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
      listBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Remove');
      listBtn.setAttribute('class', 'remove');
      listBtn.style.marginLeft = '20px';

      listBtn.addEventListener('click', removeFromList)

      parent.appendChild(listBtn);
    }


    var list;


    function addToList() {
      if (document.querySelector("ul") === null) {
        list = document.createElement('ul');
      }

      var listItem = document.createElement('li');
      var txtNode = document.createTextNode(txt.value);

      listItem.appendChild(txtNode);
      createRemoveButton(listItem);
      list.appendChild(listItem);
      document.body.appendChild(list);

      txt.value = '';
      txt.focus();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

See? now is removing the element.

Comment: Thanks .. that solves the problem. i was really stuck over this.

Comment: and now i don't need the for loop to loop through all the elements to bind an event ... that one line of code saved the trouble.. thanx again

Answer (score 0):

```html
 <body>
     <input type="text" id="txt_input">
     <input type="submit" onclick="addToList()" value="Add">

      <script>
       txt = document.getElementById('txt_input');

    window.onload = txt.focus();

    function removeFromList(e) {
      e.target.parentNode.outerHTML = "";
      txt.focus();
    }


    function createRemoveButton(parent) {
      var listBtn = document.createElement('input');
      listBtn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
      listBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Remove');
      listBtn.setAttribute('class', 'remove');
      listBtn.style.marginLeft = '20px';

      listBtn.addEventListener('click', removeFromList)

      parent.appendChild(listBtn);
    }


    var list;


    function addToList() {
      if (document.querySelector("ul") === null) {
        list = document.createElement('ul');
      }

      var listItem = document.createElement('li');
      var txtNode = document.createTextNode(txt.value);

      listItem.appendChild(txtNode);
      createRemoveButton(listItem);
      list.appendChild(listItem);
      document.body.appendChild(list);

      txt.value = '';
      txt.focus();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```